# Coredata propertiesToFetch - how does it work?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I just need to fetch values of a single attribute from an entity and do not need to fetch all the attributes unnecessarily. To achieve this I have tried using 'propertiesToFetch' property with my fetch request, but it seems to return all the attribute values for the entity.

Say, I have an entity named 'Person' which has attributes 'name', 'age', 'height', 'weight'. Now I need to get only the height values. My fetch request is as below

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
request.propertiesToFetch = ["height"]
```

Now when I retrieve the values, I expect name, age, weight for each person be nil, and all persons have only height values. 
But it's not that way, and I can still see the values for name, age, the weight which seems to me that all the properties are trying to be fetched which I want to avoid.

The above is just an example. As I am dealing with enormous data, I am trying to optimize the fetch time by picking up only the necessary values wherever possible.
Can someone please point out what I am missing here to make it proper?

Comment: use `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari is right on both counts. The result type has to be dictionary for the properties to fetch to have an effect and this question is a duplicate of the one linked to. The code in each question is nearly identical…

Answer (score 0):

I you have a large amount of data in you Entity and you don't want to load it into memory every time the object is faulted the solution is to use relationships.  Generally the large amount of data is a single property (imageData, or something similar), and can be changed to a one-to-one relationship with an entity with a single property.  This will allow you to assess the data just as easily (i.e. myObject.dataHolder.data instead of myObject.data), but you can't search or sort by it.  You can do the same things for all properties that you don't need to search or sort by, but unless those properties are very large I don't see a big return on that.

As pointed out in the comments, `propertiesToFetch` is only for dictionaryResultType and is generally not a good solution for most applications where a managedObject subclass is needed.

Comment: *"...propertiesToFetch [...] is generally not a good solution for sql backed core-data stores." This is simply not true. It's as useful with SQLite stores as with any other kind of store.

Comment: I meant that generally a person wants a managedObject subclass as a result.

Comment: Typically yes, but that's a long way from "not a good solution". It's a great solution to some problems, not good for others.